# Cant invoke toDataURL in fabricjs even when crossOrigin="anonymous"

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

When clicking on same you will get an exception: `(index):72 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

http://jsfiddle.net/mx9pggs7/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var url = "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1wM8QLpXXXXcgXVXXq6xXFXXXB/223239535/HTB1wM8QLpXXXXcgXVXXq6xXFXXXB.jpg?size=172993&height=1082&width=790&hash=62c4f508fb7a71cf577223a35c25f896";


fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) {
  oImg.set({
    'left': 0
  });
  oImg.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  oImg.set({
    'top': 0
  });

  canvas.add(oImg);
});



document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<img crossOrigin="anonymous" src="' + canvas.toDataURL('image/png') + '" />';
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the crossOrigin attribute to work it must be set before loading the image. You cannot change it on an already modified image.

Sadly it looks like that from the link provided the crossOrigin anonymous header is not set.

As you can see i added 2 image tags to the snippet. The one without crossOrigin attribute is loading correctly, the other is not loading at all.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var url = "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1wM8QLpXXXXcgXVXXq6xXFXXXB/223239535/HTB1wM8QLpXXXXcgXVXXq6xXFXXXB.jpg?size=172993&height=1082&width=790&hash=62c4f508fb7a71cf577223a35c25f896";


fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) {
  oImg.set({
    'left': 0
  });
  oImg.set({
    'top': 0
  });
  canvas.add(oImg);
}, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' });



document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<img crossOrigin="anonymous" src="' + canvas.toDataURL('image/png') + '" />';
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<div id="output">
Output will be here
</div>
<img
crossOrigin="anonymous"     src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1wM8QLpXXXXcgXVXXq6xXFXXXB/223239535/HTB1wM8QLpXXXXcgXVXXq6xXFXXXB.jpg?size=172993&height=1082&width=790&hash=62c4f508fb7a71cf577223a35c25f896" />
<img     src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1wM8QLpXXXXcgXVXXq6xXFXXXB/223239535/HTB1wM8QLpXXXXcgXVXXq6xXFXXXB.jpg?size=172993&height=1082&width=790&hash=62c4f508fb7a71cf577223a35c25f896" />
```

Comment: My example is working, and is showing you that the server where the image  is hosted does ot support crossOrigin headers. So you cannot use crossOrigin with that setup. configure your host or find another.