# JsPDF can't convert Canvas to Pdf when the canvas contains image

Tags: pdf, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

Here in this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/4pebh0yv/1/), I am trying to convert Canvas to pdf. If I remove the image adding part from the script, then the pdf is generated as expected. But with an image inside canvas, I am getting blank content in the generated pdf.

And in *downloadCanvas* function if I change the code to this -

```
canvas.discardActiveObject();
canvas.renderAll();
//const canvas = await html2canvas(document.getElementById('a'), { useCORS: true });
```

then I get this error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement':
> Tainted canvases may not be exported.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41653716/16372372 worked for me. Final code - https://jsfiddle.net/hdoegu17/. "crossOrigin=anonymous" was not placed in right place.